# Опускание дивов при мобильном виде

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

Помогите пожалуйста!!
Суть такая, уже несколько часов сижу над проектом, не могу додуматься как сделать так, чтобы в key features первые 3 особенности оставались, картинка с телефоном переносилась вниз, и под картинку переносились остальные 3 осоебенности(при мобильном разрешении) (код и картинку соотвественно прикрепляю)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MobileApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="mx-auto">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50px">
          <hr/>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle; color:#1ab798; text-align: center;font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">KEY FEATURES</td>
        <td style="width:50px">
          <hr/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="text-center my-5" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'OpenSans', sans-serif;">Nunc vulputate nibh sed congue facilisis. Curabitur posuere scelerisque neque. In sit amet lectus non lacus<br> sollicitudin cursus a vitae felis. Praesent luctus mi quis nisi interdum eleifend.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 text-center" style="top: 50px;">
        <img src="image/amet1.png" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Amet varius</p>
        <p>Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet<br> ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus<br> diam a iaculis malesuada</p>
        <img src="image/amet2.png" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Amet varius</p>
        <p>Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet<br> ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus<br> diam a iaculis malesuada</p>
        <img src="image/amet3.png" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Amet varius</p>
        <p>Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet<br> ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus<br> diam a iaculis malesuada</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center col-4">
        <img src="image/iphone.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center" style="top: 50px;">
        <img src="image/amet4.png" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Amet varius</p>
        <p>Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet<br> ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus<br> diam a iaculis malesuada</p>
        <img src="image/amet5.png" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Amet varius</p>
        <p>Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet<br> ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus<br> diam a iaculis malesuada</p>
        <img src="image/amet6.png" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Amet varius</p>
        <p>Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet<br> ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus<br> diam a iaculis malesuada</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Сам телефон]

Comment: Непонятно что вы хотите

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы на телефоне картинка съезжала вниз, и идущий за ней текст съезжал под картинку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю что вы хотели, но вот что-то

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap");
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

section {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

section>.container>*+* {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.section__title,
.section__description {
  text-align: center;
}

.section__title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section__title span {
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.section__title::before,
.section__title::after {
  position: static;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  height: 2px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background-color: #1ab798;
}

.features__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 200px));
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.features__item {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.features__item>*+* {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">

    <h2 class="section__title">
      <span>Key features</span>
    </h2>
    <p class="section__description">
      Nunc vulputate nibh sed congue facilisis. Curabitur posuere scelerisque neque. In sit amet lectus non lacus sollicitudin cursus a vitae felis. Praesent luctus mi quis nisi interdum eleifend.
    </p>

    <div class="features__container">
      <div class="features__item">
        <div class="features__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt=""></div>
        <div class="features__title">Amet varius</div>
        <div class="features__description">Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus diam a iaculis malesuada</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <div class="features__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt=""></div>
        <div class="features__title">Amet varius</div>
        <div class="features__description">Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus diam a iaculis malesuada</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <div class="features__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt=""></div>
        <div class="features__title">Amet varius</div>
        <div class="features__description">Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus diam a iaculis malesuada</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <div class="features__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt=""></div>
        <div class="features__title">Amet varius</div>
        <div class="features__description">Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus diam a iaculis malesuada</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <div class="features__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt=""></div>
        <div class="features__title">Amet varius</div>
        <div class="features__description">Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus diam a iaculis malesuada</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <div class="features__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt=""></div>
        <div class="features__title">Amet varius</div>
        <div class="features__description">Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus diam a iaculis malesuada</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <div class="features__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt=""></div>
        <div class="features__title">Amet varius</div>
        <div class="features__description">Donec posuere augue venenatis, aliquet ligula ut, tempus quam. Vivamus diam a iaculis malesuada</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```